# Create a Link to Jump to a Specific Part of a Page NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html

I need help, I'm trying to make a jump to the section in which the result of the search from the search after clicking the search button. And it works, but when I do, the value SZUKAJ disappears and shows only a box without text. Any suggestions?

```html
   <section class="page-section clearfix">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro">
          <img class="intro-img img-fluid mb-3 mb-lg-0 rounded" src="img/search.png" alt="">
          <div class="intro-text left-0 text-center bg-faded p-5 rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <span class="section-heading-upper">Wyszukiwarka</span>
            </h2>
              <form action="#">
                     <p><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Podaj nazwę kanału" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" /></p>
                     <div class="intro-button mx-auto">
                   <a href="#wynikszuk" input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" value="SZUKAJ!"/> </a>
                     </div>
                 </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="wynikszuk" class="page-section cta">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
            <div class="cta-inner text-center rounded">
              <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
                <span class="section-heading-lower">Wyniki Wyszukiwania</span>
              </h2>
              <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%" id="results">
                <tr>
                  <th>Miniaturka</th>
                  <th>Tytuł</th>
                  <th>Wyświetlenia</th>
                  <th>Liczba filmów</th>
                  <th>Subskrybenci</th>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken here: `<a href="#wynikszuk" input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl" value="SZUKAJ!"/> </a>`, specifically `"SZUKAJ!"/> </a>` should be `"SZUKAJ!"> </a>` (you were self-closing the tag, breaking the rest of your layout)

Comment: ok thank you very much. But i have another question. When i hit SZUKAJ its working but how about when i hit just enter? how can i do the same thing for that key?